# Mapreduce custom key not working

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am new to Map Reduce and trying to solve some problems in order to better learn through implementation.

**Background**:

I got a data set from movielens.com, which had ratings for various movies. I am trying to calculate the maximum ratings for a movie and sort the final output in descending order by rating count (default sorting on output is by movie id). I want something like this:

*movieId: rating_count (sort in descending order on rating_count)*

I searched on web and found that i can achieve this by using custom key. So I am trying to use it but not getting correct results.

On debugging, found that things are working fine in mapper but problem is in reducer. In reducer, input key is always the last record in my file i.e last record processed by mapper and hence i get wrong output.

I am attaching my classes for reference:

**Main class:**

```
public final class MovieLens_CustomSort {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, CompositeKey, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private IntWritable movieId;

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String row = value.toString();
        String splitRow[] = row.split("::");
        CompositeKey compositeKey = new CompositeKey(Integer.valueOf(splitRow[1]), 1);
        context.write(compositeKey, one);
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<CompositeKey, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(CompositeKey key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        Text outputKey = new Text(key.toString());

        Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            sum += iterator.next().get();
        }
        context.write(outputKey, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "max movie review");

    job.setSortComparatorClass(CompositeKeyComparator.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(CompositeKey.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}  }
```

**Custom Key:**

```
public final class CompositeKey implements WritableComparable<CompositeKey> {

private int m_movieId;
private int m_count;

public CompositeKey() {

}

public CompositeKey(int movieId, int count) {
    m_count = count;
    m_movieId = movieId;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(CompositeKey o) {
    return Integer.compare(o.getCount(), this.getCount());
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(m_movieId);
    out.writeInt(m_count);
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    m_movieId = in.readInt();
    m_count = in.readInt();
}

public int getCount() {
    return m_count;
}

public int getMovieId() {
    return m_movieId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MovieId = " + m_movieId + " , count = " + m_count;
}}
```

**Custom key comparator:**

```
public class CompositeKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {

protected CompositeKeyComparator() {
    super(CompositeKey.class, true);
}

@Override
public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
    CompositeKey c1 = (CompositeKey)w1;
    CompositeKey c2 = (CompositeKey)w2;

    return Integer.compare(c2.getCount(), c1.getCount());
}}
```

P.S : I know my key class doesn't make much sense but this is created for learning purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. problem is in CompositeKeyComparator, I was comparing on basis on count which was 1 for every record after mapper, so every record was rendered equal. Once i changed the comparison to movie id, it worked fine.